# ON DUPLICATE KEY causing timeout

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I am currently running the following SQL statement on my MySQL database:

```
INSERT INTO `Table` (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) VALUES ('a','b','c')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Col1`=`Col1`, `Col2`=`Col2`, `Col3`=`Col3`
```

However, everytime I do run it, I get the following error: `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`. It's pretty horrible, because I don't know what exactly went wrong. My intention is to update all the values of the existing row (with the exception of `id`, which is the table's primary key).

If you do have any idea, please let me know!

**EDIT:** More info... the `id` is an auto-incremented field. There is also another `UNIQUE` column (let's call it `IdentityNo`, and so what I'd like the statement to do is to: **1. insert if there is no conflict in `IdentityNo`**, and **2. update that existing row if there is a conflict** (without changing the `id`).

Comment: What are you expecting `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to do when you don't use `id` in the INSERT? Is any of the other values indexed as `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Sorry I missed out my intention, have updated the information...!

Comment: You're updating the table with the same values? That seems pointless. Maybe you mean `VALUES(Col1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to the values of the columns in the insert section of the above statement, you need to use values(column_name).
You must use something like 

`INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES ('a','b','c')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=values(Col1), Col2=values(Col2), Col3=values(Col3)`